# GAE Datastore - What happens when the data is too much?

Tags: google-app-engine

What happens when you cross the 1GB limit for free applications in Google App Engine? In paid apps, google lets you store more data and charges you for additional data stored but what about free apps?

Here are a few hypothesis:

- It throws away your *least recently used data*. **(hopefully)**
- It throws away your *least frequently used data*.
- It throws away your *oldest data*.
- It doesn't let your store anymore data and *throws an error* **(hopefully not)**

Answer (score 0):

google won't throw anything away.

The last item you listed will be the outcome, an exception is raised and no ability 
to write new data.

It's the only possible action they can take.

Randomly deleting data would be considered disastrous in most cases.

This is the same for all resources under quota, an exception will be raised when you go over.

Comment: so you're saying, the last option which i was hoping not to be true **is** true? :(

Comment: Yes that is what I am saying.

Comment: They can't possibly throw data away how can they know what is important.

Comment: okay, thanks for the info. but i guess, i myself can throw away the oldest data and continue using the app engine right? but for that i need to know what the exception is.. so can you please tell me what the exception is?

Comment: and just another quick doubt, what happens when you run out of space in HTML5 localStorage which is 5MB...?

Comment: That last one is trivial to try yourself (and post it back)